# Remove a row inside a div

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I want to insert a **"remove" button** in each of these divs, so that the **database's row and the div can be deleted** using the remove button.

Number of divs vary according to the number of rows in the database.

[It should appear as follows,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrCSb.jpg)

Showing data works just fine. But, delete (remove button) doesn't work.

**PHP**

```
    function deleteUser($connection, $userID){  //  this function calls within the "currentUsers" Function
        $sql2 = "DELETE FROM users_table WHERE user_id = '$userID' ";

        if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql2)) {
            header("Location: main.php");

        } else {
                echo "Error! ";
        }

    }


    function currentUsers($connection){
        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM users_table ";
        $result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql1);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
                $userID = $row['user_id'];
                $name = $row['name'];
                $country = $row['country'];

                echo '<div> 
                        <h3>'. $userID. " ". $name. " ". $country. '</h3>
                        <input type = "button" name = "removeButton" value = "Remove" method = "GET">
                     </div>';

                if (isset($_GET['removeButton'])) {
                    deleteUser($connection, $userID);
                }
            }
        }else{
            echo "Currently there are no users!";
        }

        mysqli_close($connection);
    }

    currentUsers($connection);


?>
```

Comment: How the remove button work?? and why work? you use `method = "GET"` in the button.

Comment: make an ajax call to complete the operation, if you don't want the use of form.

Comment: @FrayneKonok how can I do that?

Comment: wait, i post my answer.

Comment: @AnushkhaM, See the answer.

Comment: Kindly provide your Button HTML code too.

Comment: @AliKhanusiya, That is also provided at the middle of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The remove button doesnt work because you never get into deleteUser() method.

You cant just write

```
<input type = "button" name = "removeButton" value = "Remove" method = "GET">
```

as it was inside a form. For it to trigger, write it like this:

```
<form method="GET">
    <input type = "submit" name = "removeButton" value = "<?php echo $userID;?>">
</form>
```

Then, when calling

```
deleteUser($connection, $_GET['removeButton']);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But it doesn't work as I expected.

Comment: How are you expecting it to work? Tell me more so I can help you.

Comment: It removes the last div when I called the deleteUser() from the outside of while loop scope. when it called from inside the while loop, it removes all the divs. Not only the expected div. I want to remove only the div which includes the remove button I press. You may get an idea if you could see the image I attached in the main question. Thank you.

Comment: This is because all inputs are called "removeButton". If you add your userID value to the input, then you can send that specificid to deleteUser(). See my updated response.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped a lot. I tried <button type = "submit" name = "removeButton" value = "'. $userID. '" > Remove </button> and got the exact output I wanted, based on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

As the discussion from the comment, The following codes given.

**Updated HTML:**

```
<input type="button" name="removeButton" value="Remove" class="removeBtn">
```

**Javascript:**

```
var userID = "<?php echo $userID;?>";
$(".removeBtn").on("click", function(){
    $.post("page.php", { userID : userID}, function(result){
        if(result == "Success") window.location.href = "main.php";
        else alert(result);  
    });
});
```

**page.php**

```
//need the database connection
$userID = $_POST['userID'];
$sql2 = "DELETE FROM users_table WHERE user_id = '$userID' ";
if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql2)) {
    echo 'Success';
} else {
    echo "Error! ";
}
```

> If you want to remove the total div as well with the database field then use:

**Javascript:**

```
var userID = "<?php echo $userID;?>";
$(".removeBtn").on("click", function(){
    var __this = $(this);
    $.post("page.php", { userID : userID}, function(result){
        if(result == "Success"){
            __this.closest("div").remove();
            window.location.href = "main.php";
        }
        else alert(result);  
    });
});
```

> If you want to pass your `$userID` in each `input` then use:

```
<input data-userid = <?php echo $userID;?> type="button" name="removeButton" value="Remove" class="removeBtn">
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".removeBtn").on("click", function(){
    var __this = $(this);
    var userID = __this.attr("data-userid");
    $.post("page.php", { userID : userID}, function(result){
        if(result == "Success"){
            __this.closest("div").remove();
            window.location.href = "main.php";
        }
        else alert(result);  
    });
});
```

This is just an answer of your question, but you have to use this as you want. This may help you, try and let me know what happens.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I tried removing div as well as the database row. But it didn't work. I'm afraid that I have missed something in adapting your coding.

Comment: Is there anything wrong in my code? Did you found anything error?

Comment: No, I didn't notice any error in your code. Just, I couldn't adapt it in the right place, in my code.

Comment: I got the work done without javascript. I'm new for programming and perhaps, your coding would help me in the future, if you could tell me where to adapt them in my code. Thank you.

Comment: Ha ha ha, so wait for next time, It will be helpful when you understand them. Don't worry, keep it up.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'users');
 function deleteUser($connection, $userID){  //  this function calls within the "currentUsers" Function
        $sql2 = "DELETE FROM users_table  WHERE id = '$userID' ";

        if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql2)) {
            header("Location: main.php");

        } else {
                echo "Error! ";
        }

    }
   function currentUsers($connection){
        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM maps ";
        $result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql1);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
                $userID = $row['id'];
                $name = $row['name'];
                $country = $row['country'];

                echo '<div> 
                        <h3>'. $userID. " ". $name. " ". $country. '</h3>
                        <a href="main.php?removeButton='.$userID.'" style="text-decoration: none;" > <input type = "button" value="Remove Button"></a>
                     </div>';
             }
        }else{
            echo "Currently there are no users!";
        }

        mysqli_close($connection);
    }

    if (isset($_GET['removeButton'])) 
    {
        deleteUser($connection, $_GET['removeButton']);
    }

    currentUsers($connection);

?>
```